# Error parameters from Qiskit backends

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, noise

In order to build a [custom noise model in Qiskit Aer](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_noise.html#device-noise-parameters), I requested the error parameters from different backends and got 3 (9) parameters for each single-qubit (two-qubit) gate as output. However, I could not find any documentation of what these numbers are actually specifying. Based on a [previous stack-exchange question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8958/how-good-is-basic-device-noise-model-simulating-the-noise-in-the-quantum-compu?rq=1) about Qiskit's `basic_device_noise_model()`, I would guess that the first parameter is giving the gate fidelity. Is this true? What are the other 2 (8) numbers specifying?

Here is an example for a single-qubit (`id`) and a two-qubit (`cx`) gate from the backend `orense`:

```
   {'type': 'qerror',
   'operations': ['id'],
   'instructions': [[{'name': 'id', 'qubits': [0]}],
    [{'name': 'z', 'qubits': [0]}],
    [{'name': 'reset', 'qubits': [0]}]],
   'probabilities': [0.9996936442814689,
    5.460519336879117e-05,
    0.0002517505251623531],
   'gate_qubits': [[0]]},

   {'type': 'qerror',
   'operations': ['cx'],
   'instructions': [[{'name': 'id', 'qubits': [1]}],
    [{'name': 'z', 'qubits': [0]}],
    [{'name': 'reset', 'qubits': [0]}],
    [{'name': 'z', 'qubits': [1]}],
    [{'name': 'z', 'qubits': [0]}, {'name': 'z', 'qubits': [1]}],
    [{'name': 'reset', 'qubits': [0]}, {'name': 'z', 'qubits': [1]}],
    [{'name': 'reset', 'qubits': [1]}],
    [{'name': 'z', 'qubits': [0]}, {'name': 'reset', 'qubits': [1]}],
    [{'name': 'reset', 'qubits': [0]}, {'name': 'reset', 'qubits': [1]}]],
   'probabilities': [0.9893181752693058,
    0.0004106923127677822,
    0.001895703775229592,
    0.002657456705309657,
    1.1031810267579292e-06,
    5.092144099539429e-06,
    0.005698491726413379,
    2.365595624250726e-06,
    1.0919290223224507e-05],
   'gate_qubits': [[0, 1]]},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of those dicts are a `QuantumError`. You can learn more about the structure of a `QuantumError` [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.QuantumError.html). That documentation is most likely what you were looking for.

Each `instruction` is an operation being applied on the qubit(s) in `qubits`. Each value in `probabilities` corresponds to the respective operation in `instructions`.